# Can @PathVariable recieve variable defined own orignal Data type?

Tags: spring-boot, kotlin

I made controller method.
I want the method to receive variable defined by own original Data type.
like Below,

```
data class UserId(
    val value: UUID
)

@GetMapping("user/{userId}")
fun getUser(
    @PathVariable userId: UserId
) {
    userService.getUser(userId)
}
```

Of course, I know how to receive variable of String.

```
@GetMapping("user/{userId}")
fun getUser(
    @PathVariable userId: String
) {
    // I think this code is redundancy.
    val id = UserId.fromString(userId)
    userService.getUser(userId)
}
```

Can I receive variable defined own original Data Type?
Do you know any idea?

Answer (score 0):

The main question is, how do you see this working? Would you receive the data class as a serializable JSON object? If so, shouldn't that be inputted as the request body?

If there's another way you envision this working, you can always manually serialize the object later, something like:

Controller:

```kotlin
@GetMapping("user/{userId}")
fun getUser(
    @PathVariable userIdSerialized: String
) {
    userService.getUser(userIdSerialized)
}
```

Service:

```kotlin
fun getUser(userIdSerialized: String) {
    // Using Jackson
    val deserialized: UserId = mapper.readValueFromString(userIdSerialized, UserId::class.java)
}
```

But again, this should really be a request body.